How can i synchronize my Barani Meteo Helix Pro IoT device to send data at the hour exactly (and every subsequent 10 minutes)?
I sent a downlink message (consisting of the hex code for the next timestamp, when I wanted to received the message) to one of my MeteoHelix Pros via my LPN portal to port 130. I tried to move the device to the next "round" 10 min mark, i.e. to 12:20:00. Before, it returned the message 50 seconds to early (at 12:09:10). However, the result was, that i got two messages for the "same" timestamp, one at 12:19:10 and one at 12:19:22. The following messages are now received all at xx:xx:22. How do i get it to be at xx:x0:00?

If there will be a large amount of your devices you don't want to schedule uploads at the same time. That is basically DDoS on yourself by design. In that case you should consider to discern between data time and upload time.

Ahh interesting point, thanks! However, in our case with the Barani Helix IoT Pro, unfortunately, I don't think there is any possibility to discern between data time and upload time as they are identical. And as this time consist the average of all measurements carried out over the past 10 minutes, it would be lovely if there is any way we can align the time slots to be equal among all devices in order to enhance comparability between devices. I hope this makes any sense?
